# Heap Structure with Key Function in initalizer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm basically trying to implement this Heap Structure in Python and     I've editing the portions under def heap-iffy and def add but I'm not sure how to how to use the current initialize with a key function. This function will be used to extract a value from each element added to the heap; these values, in turn, will be used to order the elements. f no key function is provided, the default max-heap behavior should be used — the "lambda x:x" default value for the initialize method does just that.

```
    class Heap:
       def __init__(self, key=lambda x:x):
         self.data = []
         self.key  = key

       @staticmethod
       def _parent(idx):
         return (idx-1)//2

       @staticmethod
       def _left(idx):
         return idx*2+1

       @staticmethod
       def _right(idx):
         return idx*2+2

       def _heapify(self, idx=0):

       enter code here
       while True:
           l = Heap._left(idx)
           r = Heap._right(idx)
           maxidx = idx
           if l < len(self) and self.data[l] > self.data[idx]:
              maxidx = l
           if r < len(self) and self.data[r] > self.data[maxidx]:
              maxidx = r
           if maxidx != idx:
              self.data[idx], self.data[maxidx] = self.data[maxidx], self.data[idx]
              idx = maxidx
           else:
              break

        def add(self, x):
           enter code here
           self.data.append(x)
           i = len(self.data) - 1
           p = Heap._parent(i)
           while i > 0 and self.data[p] < self.data[i]:
              self.data[p], self.data[i] = self.data[i], self.data[p]
              i = p
              p = Heap._parent(i)

       def peek(self):
          return self.data[0]

       def pop(self):
          ret = self.data[0]
          self.data[0] = self.data[len(self.data)-1]
          del self.data[len(self.data)-1]
          self._heapify()
          return ret

       def __bool__(self):
          return len(self.data) > 0

       def __len__(self):
          return len(self.data)

       def __repr__(self):
          return repr(self.data)
```

Comment: Fix your code and indent, first.

Comment: @COLDSPEED got it done